# In Deuteronomy 24:6, what is the significance of taking the millstones?

Tags: deuteronomy, law, layers-of-meaning

In Deu. 24:6, it is written,

> <sup>6</sup> No man shall take the nether or the upper millstone to pledge: for he taketh a man's life to pledge. <sup>KJV, 1769</sup>

What is the significance of taking the millstones? Why would it be equated to taking the life of a man?

Answer (score 3):

> [Deuteronomy 24:6](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Deuteronomy-Chapter-24/): No man shall take the nether or the upper millstone to pledge: for he taketh a man's life to pledge.

The nether is the lower part of a hand mill, used for grinding corn, while the millstone is the upper.  Without the nether and the millstone, a man could not grind corn to make bread and would then likely starve. If the man owes money, the pledge must not be resolved by taking either the nether or the upper millstone: for to do so would be like taking a man's life.

For more, see [Cambridge Bible for Schools and Colleges](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/cambridge/deuteronomy/24.htm).